# C++ Disallowing certain functions if object is of a type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I've got a weird quality of life problem:

`Entity* Bob = new Camera` where Entity (abstract) is a type of object that I want in an vector array. And Camera is the specific object.

I have no problems with getting Camera to inherit and implement the functions of Entity into camera. the Camera runs fine. The problem arises when I create another object with `Entity* Joe = new Cube;`

Now I want to be able to group together Joe and Bob, but Bob, being a moving object, I want him to inherit the `ProcessKeyboard();` function, so I can use it when using Bob. But Joe doesn't move, so I'd rather Joe not even have access to the `ProcessKeyboard();` function.

Now, I could make Joe's ProcessKeyboard function do nothing, but I'd rather the compiler not allow me to to present it as an option for Joe to do.

I think my main question is what should I be looking up to solve this?

Comment: The compiler can't tell which vector elements will be `Camera` or `Cube`, that happens dynamically at run time.

Comment: Search how to implement a property entity component system (ECS). Entity should not be abstract, but a id to an entity that possesses components.

Comment: Provide `Entity` as an interface. Don't mix `Camera` and `Cube` objects in a collection where you need to use specific functionality. In short just don't throw away static type information, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Have you considered `vector<Camera>` and `vector<Cube>`. It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve by lumping any and all arbitrary things into the _same_ container. The more items in a container, the less efficient it is; you gain a lot by adding a little structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most logical solution would be:

```
class Entity
{
   virtual void Update() = 0;
}

class Camera : public Entity
{
   void Update() override {
      // ...
   }

   void ProcessKeyboard() {
      // ...
   }  
}

class Cube : public Entity
{
   void Update() override {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Then you store entities and cameras separately:

```
vector<Entity*> entities; // pointers to all your entities are here
vector<Camera*> cameras;  // additionally track Camera objects

for(auto entity : entities) {
   entity->Update();
}

for(auto camera : cameras) {
   camera->ProcessKeyboard();
}
```

> ...I want him to inherit the ProcessKeyboard(); function, so I can use
>   it when using Bob.

As you see, in order to use `ProcessKeyboard()` you don't need to inherit it; Also I must say, that because `ProcessKeyboard()` is not `virtual` there are no additional vtables involved (only for `Entity`) and no vtable lookup occur on `ProcessKeyboard()` call. And it is good.

However, if there are a lot of different "movable" objects and you don't care about performance so much... The OOP-style solution is obvious: just create an "interface" for movable objects.

```
class IMovable
{
   virtual void ProcessKeyboard() = 0;
}

class Camera : public Entity, public IMovable
{
   void Update() override {
      // ...
   }

   void ProcessKeyboard() override {
      // ...
   }  
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<Entity*> entities;  // the same approach
vector<IMovable*> movable; // additionally track all movable objects

for(auto entity : entities) {
   entity->Update();
}

for(auto object : movable) {
   object ->ProcessKeyboard();
}
```

Besides of everything was said, there is also a `dynamic_cast` but in this particular case, it sounds like *last-minute decision making*...